# Asp.Net(C#) Label Text inline

Tags: c#, asp.net

'>

ı need textbox text set DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() how to make ?
must inline

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use the `<%#%>` syntax (used for binding expressions):

```
<%# DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() %>
```

But `<%=%>` (same as `runat="server"` with `Response.Write`):

```
<%= DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() %>
```

Or `<%:%>` if in .NET 4.0 (same as `runat="server"` with `Response.Write` and `HtmlEncode`):

```
<%: DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() %>
```

See [this](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx) post of the differences between the different `<%%>` tags.

So, this should work:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="<%= DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() %>"></asp:TextBox>
```

Alternatively, in your code behind you can set this directly (in your page load event handler, for example):

```
TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
```

Comment: @Oded Not Work Your Code 
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%= DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() %>'></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Not work does not really tell me anything. What is the error message? What does visual studio say?

Comment: @oraclee: The expression posted by Oded has to be in single quotes, e.g.: `Text='<%= DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString %>'`