# Set text in TextBox with inline code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem which I'm not able to figuring out. I tried to find a solution but it doesn't work on my page... I'm trying to set text property of textbox and fill it with actual date and time.

I tried this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDateTime" runat="server" Text='<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>'>
</asp:TextBox>
```

And it suppose to be working (I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765163/asp-netc-label-text-inline)) but it only fill the textbox with

> DateTime.Now.ToString()

What is wrong? Thanks

*edit:* Btw. I don't want to set it in code behind...

Comment: You could try `Text='<%# DateTime.Now.ToString() %>'`, but then you need to call `this.DataBind()` in page_load. I would prefer Jamel's approach to assign the value in `Page_Load`.

Comment: I am convinced that there must be easier way...

Comment: have you at least tried if it works?

Comment: I tried it and it works... But when I'll be able to find problematic textbox in code behind I could just set the date there. There is problem to find it because it's hidden in FormTemplate in edit form in Telerik RadGrid... I can find it but I'm trying to find easier way

Comment: And when I do in page_load this.DataBind() it rebinds everything on page...

Comment: I dont know the telerik controls but they for sure have appropriate evenets like `DataBound` or `ItemDataBound` where you can access the `TextBox` via `item.FindControl`.

Comment: If that textbox is in a `RadGrid` `DataBind` must be called anyway, so you don't need to do it manually. Then it should work without. Then the only code necessary is: `Text='<%# DateTime.Now.ToString() %>'`

Comment: You're absolutely right... I just want to try it outside :) 

And btw. is there any way to do it on classic form without databinding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the Text to the current datetime without the use of `DataBind()` you could do that with some prep work.

In the code behind you could make a method like so:

```
protected void SetTextToCurrentDate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox myText = sender as TextBox;
    myText.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Once this is made you can simply add an `OnLoad` event to the control.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDateTime" runat="server" OnLoad="SetTextToCurrentDate"></asp:TextBox>
```

With this you do not have to find the `TextBox` in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing `TextBoxDateTime.Text=DateTime.Now.ToString()` on page load event in .cs file.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to do it in code behind. It is quite complicated structure to find this textbox...

Answer (score 0):

On your ViewLoad or PageLoad set what you included in the text in your current asp:textbox.

```
Textbox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to do it in code behind. It is quite complicated structure to find this textbox...

Comment: @JendaMatejicek If you do not want it in the code behind, state that in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Use double quotes while setting server side value

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDateTime" runat="server" Text="<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>">
</asp:TextBox>
```